# Can we do arrayformula for repeating horizontal join?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have this table :
[image]

where i want to join all data in each row start from column D to last column. I want the output just like in that C2:C5

I use this formula in C2 :

```
=JOIN(",",filter(D2:2, D2:2<>""))
```

and copy paste down for C3:C5. This is working just fine but i'm looking the way to make it as a single formula using arrayformula() in C2.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

### Classic way

Use a [query smush](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/85111204?msgid=85209465) like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  substitute( 
    trim( 
      transpose( 
        query( transpose(D2:ZZ), "", 9^9 ) 
      ) 
    ), 
    " ", 
    ", " 
  ) 
)
```

### Modern way

When the data contains spaces, the query smush pattern requires another two `substitute()`s to avoid them getting replaced with commas. Lambda functions let you avoid that by iterating the data row by row, like this:

```
=let( 
  joinRows_, lambda(d,c,byrow(c,lambda(r,if(counta(r),textjoin(d,1,r),)))), 

  joinRows_(", ", A2:C) 
)
```

See [lambda()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) and [byrow()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930).

Answer (score 1):

This approach **doesn't** use the ARRAYFORMULA function but instead uses BYROW and COUNTA to skip empty rows.

```
=BYROW(D2:100, LAMBDA(r, 
    IF(COUNTA(r), JOIN(",",TOROW(r,1)),
      IFNA(#N/A))))
```

If you want to remove empty rows you can wrap it TOCOL like this:

```
=TOCOL(BYROW(D2:100, LAMBDA(r, 
    IF(COUNTA(r), JOIN(",",TOROW(r,1)),
      IFNA(#N/A)))),1)
```